# On Mobile devices where can Facebook Business Timeline Pages be administered from?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

Facebook can be accessed on mobile devices via a web browser or via an app.

In a desktop browser Administrators can login as FBTPs to post content and use the site as their the page.

Can administrators of FBTPs login page use this same functionality on their mobile, and if so what steps do you need to take (on the browser, in the app) to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to this page in the mobile version of the site do the following:

1. Login
2. Open left sidebar
3. Scrawl down and click "All Pages" under "Pages"
4. Click the page you want to administer
5. Open the "Info" tab
6. Scroll all the way to the bottom
7. Click "Edit Settings"
8. Then you can change the following settings on the image to select what you want to do.

[image]

This will let you post as the page on the page wall. I don't use the app. But I'm pretty sure, it'll have the same option.

Comment: I added some extra detail to your answer as to how you reach the screen above, it says that this will not be visible until it is "peer reviewed".  If you are the "peer" please allow it in the answer and I will select it as the correct one.

Comment: I modified your edit a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another work around, wrote about it on my blog: http://seo-alien.com/tips-and-tricks/posting-facebook-business-page-timeline-mobile/

Comment: Answers should be able to stand by themselves. If the page you link to goes down, your answer will be useless.

Comment: Advertising for one's own stuff is not appropriate in this site.